# System of two linear equations, show that they have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

have this problem from a textbook I'm working through.

Given a system of the form

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-m_{1}x_{1}+x_{2}=b_{1}\\
 -m_{2}x_{1}+x_{2}=b_{2}\end{array}\right.$

Show that the system will have a unique solution if $m_{1}\neq m_{2}$
Now this is the first of three questions with the third asking for a geometrical explanation of the first two questions.

So I can see that m is the gradient of the lines and if the gradients are not equal that they will intersect. But I am not sure if there is another way to demonstrate the above condition without referring to the geometrical explanation. 
Any help?

Comment: Thanks for the help with my tex Jose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to show that a system has "a unique solution" is to actually **find** that solution!  Here the system is 
$-m_1x_1+ x_2= b_1$
$-m_2x_1+ x_2= b_2$

We can eliminate $x_2$ by subtracting the second equation from the first:
$(m_2- m_1)x_1= b_1- b_2$.

As long as $m_1\ne m_2$, $m_2- m_1\ne 0$ so we can divide both sides getting $x_1= \frac{b_1- b_2}{m_2- m_1}$. Now put that into either of the original equations to solve for $x_2$: $x_2= b_1+ m_1x_1= b_1+ \frac{m_1(b_1- b_2)}{m_2- m_1}$.

That $(x_1, x_2)$ pair clearly satisfies both equations and is the only pair that does.

Comment: Hi user247327, thanks for your comprehensive answer. THat is a good explanation, except for one thing. I still don't understand why that means that the solution is unique. Is it because we know that the variables are defined in terms of constants (the m's and b's) now?

Answer (score 1):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding we obtain
$$x_1(m_1-m_2)=b_2-b_1$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Hi Sonnhard, yes I actually got to there before i posted the question. I was unsure what to do from there, but from what user247327 has posted, I have to ask some questions. i.e. how do we know that that means the solution is unique?

Comment: the equation $$x_1(m_1-m_2)=b_2-b_1$$ is linear in $x_1$ and $$m_1\ne m_2$$ so we gtet only one solution, the same can we say about $$x_2$$

Comment: Ok i see how. If $$(m_1-m_2)=0$$, $x_1$ could take any value.